# How can i get rid of this letter from all my strings?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a list of games and regions in my database and i messed a few up, They are missing the end bracket so most are named like `Sonic The Hedgehog (E` but the letter E will change to many different regions.

How can i get rid of just the single bracket and letters ? It is always the last part of my string if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `preg_replace`:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\([^)]$/', '', $str);
```

This will replace a left parenthesis which is followed by any character other than right parenthesis at the end of an input with empty string.

Comment: Thanks, thought i tried that but i must of messed it up. Working now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

if it's in all strings you can just cut 3 last chars like this

```
substr($str, 0, -3);
```

And even id it's not you still don't have to use regex. You can trim all "rear" character like this

```
rtrim($str, " (E");
```

it will remove all trailing spaces, 'E's and left braces. By using trim  it will remove the same from the front also.

Comment: Its not always E though, but the first method will probably work.

Comment: Well you can mix those methods, first cut trailing character and then remove brace and space by trimming

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `preg_replace` to replace all strings.

```
$str = preg_replace('/ \(.*$/', '', $str);
```

That regular expression finds a space, followed by a right-parenthesis, followed by zero or more characters. This works on any of the following possibilities: `(`, `(E`, `(Eabcdef`